# How to animate path/Route using React.js and openStreetMap. (Cloud 9)

Tags: javascript, python, pathanimator

I am new to React.js. I have build a feature to show a set of Routes/path travelled by a vehicle on OpenStreetMap using python. But there are not enough libraries available to further animate a path in python.
How to achieve the below in React.js?

- Move/Slide Marker from start position to end position on to the path.
- Slide an image from start to end position on the the path.
  [image]

I want this type of visualization.